# Unsure of my python explanatory comments

Tags: python

I'm doing Learn Python the Hard Way exercise 15

A study drill is to explain every line with comments, but I feel unsure of my explanations. I'm looking for corrections to my mistakes and improvements. Correct term usage is my biggest worry, especially when it comes to variables and file-objects.

this is the plain code

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

This is the code with my inadequate explanatory comments.

```
#the following is what is run from commandline
#each word(?) following python is an argument
#python ex15.py ex15_example.txt


#imports the "argument variable" module from the sys package
from sys import argv

#assigns commandline arguments to variables 
script, filename = argv

#creates "txt" variable that creates a file-object of the filename variable
txt = open(filename)

#prints written string followed by filename variable
print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
#reads and prints variable "txt" which is a file object
print txt.read()

#prints string asking for raw_input
print "Type the filename again:"
#prompts you for raw_input and takes your raw_input and makes file_again variable
file_again = raw_input ("> ")

#creates txt_again file-object of file_again variable
txt_again = open(file_again)

#reads and prints txt_again file-object
print txt_again.read()
```

Comment: So ... Is this working code?  If yes, you might be better served posting this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: it's example code from python learn the hard way. he only has to comment it

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of these comments is only for you to write them and, by doing so, learning and remembering what each line does. they don't have to follow rules of proper commenting (not like anybody comments every single line in real code, what'd be using python for then? LOL)

So, with that out of the way, lemme go through each line like you did.

```
#the following is what is run from commandline
#each word(?) following python is an argument
#python ex15.py ex15_example.txt
# (Correct. )

#imports the "argument variable" module from the sys package
# (It doesn't work like that. sys is a module, 
# meaning a sis.py file stored somewhere else is accessed and interpreted. 
# And argv is an object declared within 
# said file (could be a class, a global variable, etc.
# for example. in this case, it's the list of command parameters. )
from sys import argv

#assigns commandline arguments to variables 
# (Yeah, since he's doing this, it means argv has 2 items inside, and 
# each is assigned to the respective variable).
script, filename = argv

#creates "txt" variable that creates a file-object of the filename variable
#(Yup)
txt = open(filename)

#prints written string followed by filename variable
#(This is a formatted string, similar to how you use printf in C.
# If you don't know them now, you will later, probably.)
print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
#reads and prints variable "txt" which is a file object
#(the method 'read' basically goes through the remaining unread
#lines and returns them as a big-ass string, which is then printed
# by you)
print txt.read()

#prints string asking for raw_input
print "Type the filename again:"
#prompts you for raw_input and takes your raw_input and makes file_again variable
# (yup, nothing to see here...)
file_again = raw_input ("> ")

#creates txt_again file-object of file_again variable
# (yup)
txt_again = open(file_again)

#reads and prints txt_again file-object
# (no big surprises here. BTW, if you use txt.read() again, you'll get
# an empty string. If you already know iterators from some other language,
# think of file objects as iterators of a file. Once they are used once,
# you need another one (you can reset this one, though, with some other method).
print txt_again.read()
```

Comment: I know how comments work, this was just the first exercise that I got confused on and was trying to dominate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> A study drill is to explain every line with comments.

This is a terrible exercise. Programming languages are *languages* and comments should exist only when this language falls down.

Take for example, this code:

```
print "hello world"
```

I don't need a comment to know what's happening here - its printing a string.

You need to comment things which are not obvious. For example:

```
csv = open(filename)
for line in csv[1:]:
    do_a_thing(line)
```

Now we need some comments, but not where you think.

```
csv = open(filename)
# Read the file from the second line, as the first line is a header.
for line in csv[1:]:
    do_a_thing(line)
```

Why only comment the second line? Because the first is self-explanatory, its opening a file and storing it in a variable, and the third is "doing a thing"

**Only write code to explain *why* you did something and only when the code isn't sufficient.**

Comment: (Minor: I know this is just an example, and I agree with your substantive point in real code -- the rules for learning exercises are always a little different -- but the code you've posted wouldn't actually work..)

Comment: The comment thing is just a thing to do after you complete the exercise. It never tells you to do it for actual programs, this is just for ironing out understanding.